# vue.js show/hide input field based on radio button selection

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to customize an out-of-the-box form in Vue.js where inputs are shown/hidden depending on the selection of 2 radio buttons:

```
<b-form-group label-class="ssrv-form-control">
    <div class="ssrv-5">
        <b-form-radio v-model="isOperator" name="operatorRad" value="false">Consultant</b-form-radio>
    </div>
    <div class="ssrv-0">
        OR
    </div>
    <div class="ssrv-1 rad">
        <b-form-radio v-model="isOperator" name="operatorRad" value="true">{{ userDetails.operator.description }}</b-form-radio>
    </div>
</b-form-group>
```

I have defined `isOperator` in the data (am I defining data correctly? I'm trying to modify the out-of-the-box code, not sure what this means):

```
export default {
    name: 'User-Details',
    components: {...},
    props: {...},
    data () {
        let data = {
        ...
        isOperator: true,
        ...
        };
```

and I'm trying to make this show/hide a button and input fields. I'm starting with the button as it seems simpler:

```
<b-button v-show="isOperator === true" @click="save" :block="true" size="lg" variant="primary" active-class="ssrv-form-button" class="ssrv-form-button">
    {{$t("common.form.signUp")}}
</b-button>
```

My current problem, is the button isn't showing/hiding based on the two radio buttons. If I make `isOperator: true` in the data, the page loads with the 2nd radio button selected and the button showing. When I click the second radio button, it disappears. But then when I click the original radio button again, the button doesn't show back up. I get the same result when I try to show/hide an input field, I can get it to show initially by setting `isOperator` to true, but then when I select the other radio button to make it disappear I can't make it appear again. If `isOperator` is set to false, it just never shows.

I put a `isOperator is {{ isOperator }}` p element and I can see the value is change true/false as expected, but the buttons/inputs aren't showing back up.

From my very limited understanding of Vue.js, I set the `v-model` to a variable I want an element to modify, and the `value` what that variable will be set to when the radio button is selected. Then on a separate element I want to show/hide, I can use v-if/v-show with "myvalue === true/false" to show/hide. Is this an oversimplification and I'm missing steps?

Answer (score 0):

That's because of a mismatch in the type of `isOperator` property. When you first mount the component the value of `isOperator` is a boolean (true), and then later on when you click on the radio buttons it becomes a string. You need to adjust the `value` property in your template as below:

```
<b-form-group label-class="ssrv-form-control">
    <div class="ssrv-5">
        <b-form-radio v-model="isOperator" name="operatorRad" :value="false">Consultant</b-form-radio>
    </div>
    <div class="ssrv-0">
        OR
    </div>
    <div class="ssrv-1 rad">
        <b-form-radio v-model="isOperator" name="operatorRad" :value="true">{{ userDetails.operator.description }}</b-form-radio>
    </div>
</b-form-group>
```